# For xml path returns null instead of nothing

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml-path, select-for-xml

I thought that following query suppose to return nothing, but, instead, it returns one record with a column containing `null`:

```
select *
from ( select 1 as "data"
       where 0 = 1
       for xml path('row') ) as fxpr(xmlcol)
```

If you run just the subquery - nothing is returned, but when this subquery has an outer query, performing a `select` on it, `null` is returned.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Yes, I misread your post, initially. Apologies.

Comment: @Larnu, no problems, buddy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will try to *predict* the type. Look at this

```
SELECT tbl.[IsThereAType?] + '_test'
      ,tbl.ThisIsINT       + 100
FROM
(
    SELECT NULL AS [IsThereAType?]
          ,3 AS ThisIsINT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'abc'
          ,NULL
    --UNION ALL 
    --SELECT 1  
    --    ,NULL
) AS tbl;
```

The first column will be *predicted* as string type, while the second is taken as `INT`. That's why the `+` operator on top works. Try to add a number to the first or a string to the second. This will fail.

Try to uncomment the last block and it will fail too.

The *prediction* is done at a very early stage. Look at this, where I did include the third `UNION ALL` (invalid query, breaking the type):

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set 
N'SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT NULL AS [IsThereAType?]
          ,3 AS ThisIsINT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ''abc''
          ,NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1
          ,NULL

) AS tbl';
```

The result returns "IsThereAType?" as `INT`! (I'm pretty sure this is rather random and might be different on your system.)
Btw: Without this last block the type is `VARCHAR(3)`...

### Now to your question

A *naked* XML is taken as `NTEXT` (altough this is deprecated!) and needs `,TYPE` to be predicted as `XML`:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT ''blah'' FOR XML PATH(''blub'')';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT ''blah'' FOR XML PATH(''blub''),TYPE';
```

The same wrapped within a sub-select returns as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` resp. `XML`

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM(SELECT ''blah'' FOR XML PATH(''blub'')) AS x(y)';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM(SELECT ''blah'' FOR XML PATH(''blub''),TYPE) AS x(y)';
```

Well, this is a bit weird actually...
An XML is a *scalar value* taken as `NTEXT`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `XML` (depending on the way you are calling it). But it is not allowed to place a *naked* scalar in a sub-select:

```
SELECT * FROM('blah') AS x(y) --fails
```

While this is okay

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT 'blah') AS x(y)
```

### Conclusio:

The query parser seems to be slightly inconsistent in your special case:

Although a sub-select cannot consist of one scalar value only, the `SELECT ... FOR XML` (which returs a scalar actually) is not rejected. The engine seems to interpret this as a `SELECT` **returning** a scalar value. And this is perfectly okay.

This is usefull with nested sub-selects as a column (correlated sub-queries) to nest XML:

```
SELECT TOP 5 t.TABLE_NAME
            ,(
              SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
              WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                AND c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
              FOR XML PATH('Column'),ROOT('Columns'),TYPE
             ) AS AllTablesColumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t;
```

Without the `FOR XML` clause this would fail (*...more than one value...* / *...Only one column...*)

### Pass a generic `SELECT` as a parameter?

Some would say this is not possible, but you can try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestType(@x XML)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT @x AS BringMeBack;
GO

--The SELECT must be wrapped in paranthesis!
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestType((SELECT TOP 5 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML PATH('x'),ROOT('y')));
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty **XML** Data is treated as **NULL** in SQL Server.

```
select *
from ( select 1 as "data"
       where 0 = 1
       for xml path('row') ) as fxpr(xmlcol)
```

The Subquery will be executed first and the result of the subquery i.e **(Empty Rowset)** will be converted to **XML** therefore, getting **NULL** Value.

Comment: Will it be converted to **XML** even though, there is no `type` option? When you run `exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'select * from ( select 1 as "data" for xml path(''row'') ) as fxpr(xmlcol)'`, it says, that the column has nvarchar(max) type.